# Java interface type as constructor parameters

Tags: java, oop

hi
i am learning about Java interfaces. I read in Java tutorial that an interface is a reference type. Say I declare an interface

```
public interface INT {       public void dosomething();     }
```

and i have 3 classes, class A{}, B{} and C{}.

```
class A{} implements INT. 
class B{} extends A{} and implements INT. 
class C{} implement INT.
```

then i have another class D{} that has constructor

```
public class D{
  private INT a,b,c ;
  public D( INT a1, INT b1 , INT c1)  {
      a = a1; 
      b = b1;
      c = c1;
  }
  ....
}
```

and then in main(), i instantiate a D object

```
D myobject = new D( new A(), new B(), new C() );
```

It is said that objects that are not related by class hierarchy can be used to interact with each other using interface. So in the above class, class C and A are not related and now the interface allows them to "talk" to each other? am i understanding this correct? what other advantages is there to declaring the constructor to be of interface type instead of the actual class type , as opposed to

```
private A a, B b, C c ;
public D( A a1, B b1 , C c1) {
   a=a1; b=b1;c=c1;
}
```

Is it something to do with polymorphism? sorry, this is my first attempt at OO, so am lacking some understanding here.

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. INT is a name for a constant.

Comment: Its just an example. Naming conventions excluded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The huge advantage of using an interface type in a method (or constructor) parameter is that other programmers can call it and pass in their own classes that implement the interface. Classes that you didn't know about and which didn't even exist when you wrote the method/constructor. If you use concrete classes, callers have to use those classes, subclass them or change your code, all of which restrict them much more than implementing an interface.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is absolutely correct.

The advantage of using interface instead of real class is that you expose only the communication interface of the object and not the way the object is implemented. It allows you to change the implementation in any time without breaking the client code.

This thing is called encapsulation: hiding the implementation details from the outside of the class. It is always a good thing.

About communication: they can't communicate directly. But you can call method dosomething on any of the passed objects, because they all implement the same interface. So, somewhere inside object D you can write:

```
a1.dosomething(); // called the method of A
b1.dosomething(); // called the method of B
c1.dosomething(); // called the method of C
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. By the way, is it `a.dosomething()`, or `a1.dosomething`? because a1 is already assigned to private instance variable a, i thought it should be `a.dosomething()`. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Michael Borgwardt's excellent reply. I would add that as you program you will find uses for interfaces which were not apparent when you started. e.g. Interfaces are very useful in unit tests for creating mock objects.

They are also useful when you come to refactor your code and you know that D only needs the methods in INT. If A,B,C has other methods, you know you can change (or remove) them without directly impacting D.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by "class C and A are not related and now the interface allows them to "talk" to each other", but your code looks correct.

Comment: thanks for replying. What i mean is class C is not a subclass of A, not like B.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> So in the above class, class C and A
>   are not related and now the interface
>   allows them to "talk" to each other?

Not exactly. You seem to understand the whole thing correctly, but this part is vague. It's not that interface allows them to talk to each other, it allows everyone to talk to them in a uniform way, without even knowing what classes represent a particular interface in a particular case. Of course, "everyone" includes those classes as well, so they can talk to each other too, so you are not wrong, but that's just irrelevant. In your case the interface allows class D to talk to classes A, B and C, and possibly to many other interface implementations that you can be even unaware of.

An interface defines what an object can do. A class defines how it does that. It is called separating implementation from interface. Polymorphism is a mechanism that allows this. When you call an interface method and an implementing class method is called, it's polymorphism.